# How to fit image so that there will be no white spaces beside my image?

Tags: html, css

I am limited to use only html and css for this project. I try extending the width but that leaves me having horizontal scroll and I don't want to do that. I also try using px as a measurement but that doesn't work either.

```
<img src="img/gallery.jpg" style="width:100%;height:90%;white-space:nowrap">
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsxrk.png

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mcve], and then edit your question accordingly. _“I try extending the width but that leaves me having horizontal scroll”_ - could for example be due to the fact that you did not overwrite the default margins for html/body - but if you only show us one line of code as a “problem description”, impossible to tell if that’s your issue, or something else.

Comment: Use it as a background-image of your element and then `.your-element{background-size:cover;}`

Comment: @misorude I'm new here and I attach an image to this thread but I think it didn't work so uhm how.

Comment: Are you sure some of your containers don't have 5px padding?

Comment: An image in most cases doesn’t help much either (although here it looks as if my guess regarding default body margins could be right) - how you are supposed to present your problem, is explained in the articles I referred you to.

Comment: Do your body have initial padding? Can you try body { padding: 0; }

Answer (score 0):

use `width:100%` as shown below:

```
img{
  width:100%
}
```

Comment: I already did that but that doesn't work either 
    <img src="img/gallery.jpg" style="width:100%;height:90%;white-space:nowrap">

Answer (score 0):

You need to use object-fit property on your image. Here is a demo:

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: Depending on his browser support, if he needs IE, this is not usable

Answer (score 0):

There are a few known way of removing white spacing. Here are a the best two, IMO:

1. Set the font size of the parent to be 0px:

```css
div {
  background-color: orange;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.nows {
  font-size: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
</div>
<div class="nows">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
</div>
```

2. Use comments to mitigate the white space in the code

```css
div {
  background: orange;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
</div>
<div><!--
  --><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150"><!--
  --><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150"><!--
--></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
   margin:0px;
   padding:0px;
}
```

I posted the same problem on other forum and this works. Thanks for the help.